# CSS displaying in design view not at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, css, visual-studio-2010

I have a Master Page based Web site that has menu functionality. CSS is read from a Style.css file successfully. I have now added a seperate Login.aspx page which functions fine, but does not pick up the Account.css file, which has the specific css for the Login page. I do not want the login page to refernence the master page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="Login" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Account.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                 $('.grid_12').fadeIn(1750);
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

I would appreciate any insight, as I have tried referencing the Account.css file path every way i can think of:

```
href="./Account.css"
href="Account.css"
href="~/Account.css"
```

I have now placed the Login.aspx page and Account.css file in a new login folder at website root.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML of the CSS reference. Not sure why you even mentioned the masterpage since it has absolutely nothing to do with the problem (as far as I can tell). It sounds like you are just having a problem referencing a CSS file from an ASPX page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a region that your are using form authentication.

If yes then you can use

```
 <location path="Account.css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Inside

```
<appSettings></appSettings>
```

Else you can use

```
<style type="text/css" src='<%= ResolveUrl("Account.css")%>'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, very much appreciated. In the end I placed a web.config file in the login folder allowing anonymous users access to all the resources in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are hosting your site on IIS in a virtual directory. If you do that, your path must reflect the virtual directory.

```
href="/virtualDir/Account.css"
```

To do this is asp.net use [`ResolveClientUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx)

```
href="<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Account.css") %>"
```